# Kustomize metadata.name for a specific kind:

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kustomize

I'am new to Kustomize, and i would like to know:

- How to "patch" metadata.name in a specific yaml like kind: RedisInstance.

I have tried to set a nameSuffix to a specific yaml (kind: RedisInstance), but it didn't worked.

Kustomization.yaml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

namespace: community-organization-uat-product

bases:
- ../../../../common/base/custom/gcp
- ../../../../common/base/custom/gcp/organization

commonAnnotations:
  cnrm.cloud.google.com/managed: "true"
  cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: community-organization-uat-product

patchesStrategicMerge:
- 1-cXXXXX-patch.yaml
- 3-mXXXXX-patch.yaml
- 4-mXXXXX-patch.yaml
- 5-cXXXXX-patch.yaml
- 6-mXXXXX-patch.yaml
- 7-memorystore-patch.yaml
```

This is my patch:

7-memorystore-patch.yaml

```
apiVersion: redis.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: RedisInstance
metadata:
  name: memorystore-redis
spec:
  displayName: memorystore-redis-organization-community-uat
  memorySizeGb: 2
  redisVersion: REDIS_5_0
  reservedIpRange: 10.1XXXXX/29
```

memorystore.yaml

```
apiVersion: redis.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
kind: RedisInstance
metadata:
  name: memorystore-redis
spec:
  displayName: Value defined by Kustomize
  region: XXXX
  connectMode: PRIVATE_SERVICE_ACCESS
  locationId: usXXXX
  memorySizeGb: Value defined by Kustomize
  redisVersion: REDIS_5_0
  reservedIpRange: Value defined by Kustomize
  tier: BASIC
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with the `patchesStrategicMerge`: the `name` field is used to match resources to which the patch should be applied, so either:

- you specify the old name, the resource gets matched but the name is not changed
- you specify the new name and the resource does not get matched

The good news is that it can be done with the [patchesJson6902](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/pages/reference/kustomize.html#patchesjson6902):

**Kustomization.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

# ...

patchesJson6902:
  - target:
      group: redis.cnrm.cloud.google.com
      version: v1beta1
      kind: RedisInstance
      name: memorystore-redis
    path: redisInstanceNamePatch.yaml
```

**redisInstanceNamePatch.yaml**

```yaml
- op: replace
  path: /metadata/name
  value: NewName
```

> All of the fields of the **target**, i.e. group, version, kind and name are mandatory

> You may specify multiple operations in the same patch file